# Air Mobile App List ItemRenderer scolling issue

Tags: list, mobile, air, flash-builder, itemrenderer

Having a werid issue.

If I return a larger number of rows of data then what can be displayed to on screen
when I start to scroll through the list Data from record 1 is being duplicated on
the next display item on the scroll

Example  10 data records
1
2
3
4
displayed

start scrolll
5  is diplaying 1 data
6 may display 1 or 2 data
and so on

there are 10 records displayed in the list
but the information is incorrect.

Here is the code

```
        protected function display_gas_pricesResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
        currentState='start_here';
        this.list.dataProvider=null;
        this.list.dataGroup.invalidateDisplayList();
        label_waterway.text=this.BoaterObject.waterway;
        var _itemRenderer:IFactory=this.list.itemRenderer;
        this.list.itemRenderer=null;
        this.list.itemRenderer=_itemRenderer;
        this.list.dataProvider=TypeUtility.convertToCollection(display_gas_pricesR esult.lastResult);
        this.list.validateDisplayList();
        }



<s:List id="list"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    change="list_changeHandler(event)"
    contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
    pageScrollingEnabled="true"
    borderVisible="true"
    scrollSnappingMode="leadingEdge"
    itemRenderer="renderers.ir_gas_prices">
 <s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
 </s:layout>
</s:List>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        width="100%" color="#000000"
        creationComplete="itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
        autoDrawBackground="false" contentBackgroundAlpha="0">
        <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout gap="1"
        paddingBottom="5"
        paddingLeft="5"
        paddingRight="5"
        paddingTop="5"
        verticalAlign="middle"/>
        </s:layout>
        <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
        if (data.gas_price_id == '0')
        {
        currentState='no_prices';

        }
        else
        {
        currentState='show_price';
        label_name.text=data.name;
        label_status.text=data.status;
        label_gas.text=data.gas_price;
        label_diesel.text=data.diesel_price;
        label_date.text=data.date;
        label_boatname.text=data.boat_name;
        }
        }
        ]]>
        </fx:Script>
        <s:states>
        <s:State name="show_price"/>
        <s:State name="no_prices"/>
        </s:states>
        <s:BorderContainer width.show_price="100%" height.show_price="100%" cornerRadius.show_price="10"
           dropShadowVisible.show_price="true">
        <s:layout.show_price>
        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="5"/>
        </s:layout.show_price>
        <s:VGroup width="15%"
          horizontalAlign="center">
        <s:Image width="56"
         height="46"
         source="@Embed('assets/basic1-088.png')"/>
        <s:Label id="label_status" includeIn="show_price" width="100%" color="#662100" fontSize="18"
         text="Label" textAlign="center"/>
        </s:VGroup>
        <s:VGroup width="100%"
          gap="1">
        <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:Label id="label_name" includeIn="show_price" width="100%" color="#662100"
         fontSize="20" fontWeight="bold" text="Label"/>
        <s:Label includeIn="no_prices"
         fontSize="16"
         text="Sorry no one has posted any fuel prices yet.&#xd;Be the first to post fuel prices on this water way.&#xd;Click the add button "/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup includeIn="show_price"
          width="100%"
          horizontalAlign="left"
          paddingLeft="20">
        <s:VGroup gap="1"
          horizontalAlign="center"
          verticalAlign="top">
        <s:Label fontSize="18"
         fontWeight="bold"
         text="Gas"/>
        <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:Label fontFamily="_typewriter"
         fontSize="24"
         fontWeight="bold"
         text="$"/>
        <s:Label id="label_gas"
         color="#FF0303"
         fontFamily="_typewriter"
         fontSize="24"
         fontWeight="bold"
         text="Label"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>


        <s:VGroup gap="1"
          horizontalAlign="center"
          verticalAlign="top">
        <s:Label fontSize="18"
         fontWeight="bold"
         text="Diesel"/>
        <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:Label fontFamily="_typewriter"
         fontSize="24"
         fontWeight="bold"
         text="$"/>
        <s:Label id="label_diesel"
         color="#00CA26"
         fontFamily="_typewriter"
         fontSize="24"
         fontWeight="bold"
         text="Label"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
        <s:Spacer width="20%"
          height="10"/>
        <s:VGroup width="50%"
          gap="1"
          horizontalAlign="right">
        <s:Label id="label_date"
         width="100%"
         fontSize="16"
         text="Label"
         textAlign="right"/>
        <s:HGroup width="100%"
          horizontalAlign="right">
        <s:Label fontSize="16"
         fontWeight="bold"
         text="By:"/>
        <s:Label id="label_boatname"
         fontSize="16"
         text="Label"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
        </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
        </s:BorderContainer>
        </s:ItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 0):

ItemRenderers are reused for perfomance sakes, when List.useVirtualLayout == true (which is the default). 
To make it reusable, make sure that all labels etc. are reset to their default values, whenever its data changes.
To achieve this, it's quite common to override the

```
set data(value:Object):void
```

function, that is called whenever new data is set to the renderer.

The "creationComplete" Event will fire, AFAIK, only once, when the renderer is created, meaning your display won't be updated correctly.